# VBA excel - change two cell's values based on each other, when either cell is changed

Tags: vba, excel

I trying to make a currency converter on excel.

```
Cell B1 = exchange rate
cell B2 = base currency amount
cell B3 = counter currency amount.
```

Example:

```
B1 = 1.3, B2 = Euro amount, B3 = USD amount.
```

All three cells are connected to one another by a formula `B3 = B1*B2`.

I want to be able to enter a value at `B2`, and `B3` automatically updates itself `(B3 = B2*B1)`

When I enter value at `B3`, and `B2` updates itself `(B2 = B3/B1)`.

The below code is the best I can come up with, but it creates an out of stack space error because (*I guess, it goes into an infinite loop (when `B2` is updated, `B3` updates itself, which in turn updates `B2` again...*).

Any suggestion?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim EUR As Range
    Set EUR = Range("b2")

    Dim USD As Range
    Set USD = Range("b3")

    If Not Application.Intersect(EUR, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("B3").Value = Range("B2") * Range("B1")
    Else
        If Not Application.Intersect(USD, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2").Value = Range("B3") / Range("B1")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: try to keep the values in integers first, and then calculate.

Comment: Dear Guy, thanks for your comment, but even if they are all integers it still won't work. All cells are supposed to be numbers, not formula.

Comment: try to debug it, and tell which line provide the error.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640

Comment: @user1586765 will you be downloading `Curr rates` from a third party data vendor? If so solutions could be proposed accordingly.

Comment: did any of the time we spent writing answers help? if so you can either up-vote attempts or mark one of them as correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why MS Excel crashes and closes during Worksheet\_Change Sub procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

If the crash is indeed because of an infinite loop, you could try disabling Excel events in the beginning of your macro, and re-enabling them in the end.

Snipplet, based of [this post](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/03/disabling-excel-events.html):

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

' Your code

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Seems like you missed my link in the comment that I posted above? :)

Comment: Seems that comments are not answers, @SiddharthRout . If your link answers the question, you should've posted its gist as an answer, or flagged the question as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

something like this would be a bit easier to read. You might need to play around with the formulas as I'm not 100% sure what you're doing:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    Range("B3") = Range("B2") * Range("B1")
End If

If Target.Address = "$B$3" Then
    Range("B2") = Range("B3") / Range("B1")
End If

End Sub
```